# How to run production build in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, dev-to-production

I have worked to a VueJs project locally. Now I have to upload it on a VM of my university and it will become public. I think I should not upload the entire directory but only the 'dist' directory that I created with the command:

```
npm run build
```

First question: Is it correct?

Second question: How do I run the server now? For local's test I used to run it with the command:

```
npm run serve
```

but I think now I should use some other commands.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for questions:

1. Yes. It is correct.
2. Usually, you will need to serve the dist folder in a web server. Like [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or [apache](https://www.apache.org/).

It will work serving your `index.html`, inside `/dist` folder generated in the build step of your vuejs application.

Obs.: you should not serve your application in **production** with `npm run serve` as it is a development server monothreaded.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I server it with apache? On the VM the are other applicacation served with apache. Can I do it remotely or should I ask to the VM admin to do something?

Comment: You just have to share with admin your dist folder, and he will serve it in a new directory. If you would like to do it yourself you can install an apache or nginx in your machine and serve your dist folder (it will not be public available, but you can have an ideia on how it works. Installing a local instance of nginx or apache should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

just simply

> npm run build

Copy index.html and /dist/ folder into your website root directory. Done.

Answer (score 0):

1. The command `npm run build` is correct for preparing the project for deployment.
2. You don't need to run the command `npm run serve` like you do on local.

What you will need for deployment after running the command `npm run build`  are:

**dist** folder and **index.html** file.

You could deploy your project to any hosting provider you choose.

I will use aws s3 as example for a static application (The process is almost the same in other platforms).

1. Login to aws
2. Select s3
3. Create a new bucket (Give it a preferred name and select region)
4. Enable the option for **Static Website Hosting** on the bucket you just created.
   The fileds for **Index Document** and **Error Document** should be set to **index.html**
5. Set Bucket Permission (Add Bucket Policy)

Paste this into the bucket policy editor and save.
Change **your-bucketName** to the created bucket name

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucketName/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

6. Upload the files (**build.js** in the **dist** folder and **index.js**)

   1. Click on your bucket name
   2. Select upload at the top-menu
   3. Upload the files indicated above
7. Create a folder with name as **dist** inside your bucket and move the **build.js** inside.
8. Click on **All Buckets** to go back. Select **Properties** of your deployed bucket at the top-right menu and
   click on **Endpoint** to lunch your hosted site.